# Oracle Auto PDF Export

Tags: oracle, pdf, export

I am on the search for a way to auto export PDF-Files on a Path from a Oracle11 DB. I can't find a way on my searching. I only found to do that manually.
But I want create a few PDFs every day.

Comment: You can't directly export to pdf. you need to spool as text or csv then you can convert into pdf. There are lots of jars that can do this task. You need to write a small script to convert all txt or csv into pdf.

Comment: This might help. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_creating_a_pdf_document.htm